# How to save List<Point> into preferences and get List<Point> from preferences in flutter?

Tags: serialization, flutter, dart

Error while using **[json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable)**

json_serializable:json_serializable on .../sign_point_model.dart:
Error running JsonSerializableGenerator
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `valList` because of type `Point<num>`.
None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_serializable` doesn't know how to convert a `Point` into JSON. Since you know it's just a pair of `num`s you could easily convert the list yourself.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
  var points = [
    Point(Offset(123, 456), PointType.tap),
    Point(Offset(3.14159, 3.16227), PointType.move),
  ];

  var simplified =
      points.map((e) => [e.offset.dx, e.offset.dy, e.type.index]).toList();
  String j = json.encode(simplified);
  print(j);

  var decoded = json.decode(j) as List;
  var asPoints = decoded
      .map((e) => Point(Offset(e[0], e[1]), PointType.values[e[2]]))
      .toList();
  print(asPoints);
}
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Offset'

Comment: List<Point> pointList = _signatureCanvas.exportPoints();
                        var simplified =
                            pointList.map((e) => [e.offset, e.type]).toList();
                        String jsonString = jsonEncode(simplified);
                        print(jsonString);

Comment: `e.offset` is apparently an `Offset`, not a basic type. What is your `Point`? You'll need to encode its values too.

Comment: enum PointType { tap, move }

class Point {
  Offset offset; 
  PointType type;

  Point(this.offset, this.type);
}

// Offset(dx, dy) from geometry.dart class

Comment: Ah, that's a different `Point`. Try `var simplified = points.map((e) => [e.offset.dx, e.offset.dy, e.type.index]).toList();` and `var asPoints = decoded.map((e) => Point(Offset(e[0], e[1]), PointType.values[e[3]])).toList();`

Comment: Please elaborate about this line.
var asPoints = decoded.map((e) => Point(Offset(e[0], e[1]), PointType.values[e[3]])).toList();

Comment: How to use this??

                var simplified = _points
                    .map((e) => [e.offset.dx, e.offset.dy, e.type.index])
                    .toList();
                var asPoints = jsonDecode("source???")
                    .map((e) =>
                        Point(Offset(e[0], e[1]), PointType.values[e[3]]))
                    .toList();

Comment: Replace the two similar lines in the answer, with those two new lines.

Comment: Updated the answer to show complete example of encoding and decoding.

Comment: var simplified return list. So, when decoding what "stringSource??" should I use? I didn't get it. Please elaborate.

Comment: The string you got by encoding the list, which you earlier saved to shared preferences, and have now retrieved from there.

Comment: Error when decoding:

var asPoints = jsonDecode(j)
                    .map((e) =>
                        Point(Offset(e[0], e[1]), PointType.values[e[3]]))
                    .toList();
                print(asPoints);

Comment: DECODING: var asPoints = jsonDecode(j)
                    .map((e) =>
                        Point(Offset(e[0], e[1]), PointType.values[e[2]]))
                    .toList();